# Are there any html Sanitizer() API configs that allow javascript execution?

Tags: web-browser, xss, javascript

I'm talking specifically about the HTML Sanitizer API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Sanitizer_API

The API allows you to configure the sanitizer with a list of allowed elements and attributes. Script tags are removed even when they're in the allowed elements list and javascript event handlers like onerror, onclick, etc are also stripped even when they're in the allow list.

I'm wondering if there are any known configurations that allow javascript execution?

I'm also interested in what kind of approach one might take to figure this out.

Comment: What are you even trying to achieve? The main purpose of the Sanitizer API is to prevent cross-site scripting attacks. If you *want* script execution, then what do you need the Sanitizer API for?

Comment: I'm staring at a prototype pollution issue that would allow me to pollute the configuration object that's being passed to the sanitizer api. Wondering if there's some configuration that would result in script execution.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.

Comment: Not aware of any configuration that would help you. As for methods, deep code review + run time debugging or fuzzing (maybe with hackvertor) would be my go to approaches